# Count the number of messages in protocol buffer file

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am currently writing the java code to check the number of messages in a protocol buffer file *.pb

I would like to know if there is meta-data or header that contains the information of number of messages in the protobuf file?
I am looping through the whole file, and I think there should be a better way to do it.

```
while ((m = message.getParserForType().parseDelimitedFrom(input)) != null) {
        recordCount++;
    }
```

Thanks
David

Comment: You are trying to read a `.proto` file or a `.pb` file?

Comment: I am trying to read .pb file

Answer (score 1):

There is no header or anything that will tell you the number of messages in the file. That format just consists of a length prefix in varint format, followed by a message payload, repeated for as many messages as you have.

However, you could in principle count the number of messages in a much more efficient way. If you just want to know how many there are, you could read the length prefixes and skip over the actual message payloads without parsing them.